# Авторесайзинг @Html.EditorFor (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть `@Html.EditorFor` нужно его раширять в высоту по мере заполнения текстом

Вот код:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.question, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Вопрос" } })
```

вот сам CSS стиль

```css
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  position:relative;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ffcf00;
   border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
  background-image: none;
  
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, -webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
       -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s, box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

ВопроУ , как реализовать авто расширение?

Comment: Чем Вас JS-based решения не устраивают?

Comment: я пробовал заюзать это http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ касательно класса на едитфоре, не работает :( @AntonKomyshan

Answer (score 0):

В общем трабл решил.

Проблема была в том что нужно было юзать такую конструкцию, тогда все окей

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { @class = "form-control" })
```